# How does Jshell work internally? Does it compile each input statement?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I just discovered Jshell which is a Read-Evaluate-Print Loop (REPL). From the documentation of OpenJDK, Jshell evaluates declarations, statements, and expressions as they are entered and immediately shows the results. My question is does Jshell compile each input statement and then execute it with JVM or it doesn't need to compile at all?

Comment: From [this introduction - JShell Architecture section](https://serengetitech.com/en/blog/tech/introducing-jshell-a-guide-for-using-the-new-java-9-feature), JShell will compile the input as bytecode and execute with JVM.